# Delayed Job and S3 Upload cant finish process , but also dont give any error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3

I am working on rails project, and I am generating excel files form User model and then uploading to amazon s3! Everything so far work's perfect, but I want to use also delayed job, and there is where the problem comes,
when I call the method with delayed, the job cant complete, but also I don't get any error! If I run delayed jobs log i got this:

```
[Worker(host:pure pid:11063)] Starting job worker
[Worker(host:pure pid:11063)] Job Delayed::PerformableMethod (id=77) RUNNING
[Worker(host:pure pid:11063)] Job Delayed::PerformableMethod (id=78) RUNNING
[Worker(host:pure pid:11063)] Job Delayed::PerformableMethod (id=79) RUNNING
[Worker(host:pure pid:11063)] Job Delayed::PerformableMethod (id=80) RUNNING
```

it seems like the job has stuck and can't finishes the process!

Here are all of my Methods:

User's Controller:

```
 def export
    if params[:search]
      @users = User.all.order('created_at DESC')
    else
      @users = User.search(params[:search]).order('created_at DESC')
    end
    User.delay.export_users_to_xlsx(@users, current_user)
    redirect_to action: :index
  end
```

User's Model:

```
def self.export_users_to_xlsx(users, user)
    file = User.create_excel(users)
    s3_upload = FileManager.upload_to_s3(file)
    link = s3_upload[:file].presigned_url(:get, expires_in: 10.days) if s3_upload
end

def self.create_excel(users)
    Spreadsheet.client_encoding = 'UTF-8'
    filename = "#{Rails.root}/tmp/#{ DateTime.now.strftime("%m%d%Y%H%M%S") }_users.xlsx"
    array = [["Name", "Balance","State","Address"]]

    users.each do |user|
        array.push([user.name,user.balance,user.state,user.address])
    end
    ExportXls.create_spreadsheet(array,filename)
end
```

and here is the lib for creating the spreadsheet:

```
class ExportXls

    def self.create_spreadsheet(content,filename)
        Spreadsheet.client_encoding = 'UTF-8'
        book = Spreadsheet::Workbook.new
        sheet1 = book.create_worksheet
        content.each_with_index do |row,index|
            row.each do |column|
                sheet1.row(index).push column
            end
        end
        book.write filename
        return filename
    end
end
```

And this is the method for uploading the file to S3 , which is also in lib :

```
def self.upload_to_s3(temp_file)
    s3 = Aws::S3::Resource.new
    begin
      obj = s3.bucket(ENV['S3_BUCKET']).object(File.basename(temp_file))
      obj.upload_file(temp_file)
      File.delete(temp_file) if File.exists?(temp_file)
       { :result => 'success', :file => obj }
    rescue Aws::S3::Errors::ServiceError => error
       { :result => 'failed', :message => error.message }
    end
  end
```

Any suggestions why i cant get the delayed job to get work?

I am using delayed_job_active_record gem!

Sorry for my bad English!

Comment: Unrelated to your problem but why are you using class methods in User model when you later pass user instance anyway. Instance model would make things easier.

Comment: Did you try "print debugging" to see where your delayed job gets stuck? And did you try running `User.delay.export_users_to_xlsx(users, user)` from rail console?

Comment: Michal Szyndel , what do you mean to "print debugging" ? and when i can run this?

Comment: I did debugging, and also, I run the command from the console, but I don't get any errors at all!

Comment: So you did put a print at the end of `self.upload_to_s3` method and it was reached but the delayed job is still running?